# If condition is met copy cell.values in one row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sorry but I asked this question already yesterday, but it seems like I wasn't clear enough with my wishes, so I try it again this time.

My code Looks like this right now:

```
If OptionButton11.Value = True Then

        Set Rng = Sheets("Table").Range(TextBox3.Value & TextBox1.Value + 1 & ":" & TextBox3.Value & lastrow)
        Set kst = Sheets("Table").Range(TextBox2.Value & TextBox1.Value + 1 & ":" & TextBox2.Value & lastrow)
            For Each Cell In Rng
                If Cell.Value = TextBox10.Value Then
                   Cell.copy Cell.Offset(, 1)
                   Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = kst.Value
               End If
            Next Cell

End If
```

In this scenario, the user has the opportunity to use textboxes to define where his values are in the worksheet and what the macro has to look for.

- Textbox1.Value  defines where the headings in the worksheet are.
  `
- Textbox2.Value defines where the value can be found
- Textbox3.Value is the criteria after the value is filtered

And

- Textbox.Value 4 is the required criteria.

I would like to achieve with this code; that whenever Textbox4.Value is found in the range of Textbox3.Value, TextBox2.Value and Textbox3.Value are copied into the first free columns in the worksheet.

My Problem right now is, that

```
Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = kst.Value
```

do not copy the values in the first empty column, but add them horizontally to each freely available row in a column.

I already tried it with `xlDown` instead of `xlToLeft` but then a runtimerror  (1004) appears.

Has anyone a suggestion how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Dim a variable as lastrow, and update that each time before you paste the values. If you search for lastrow within the `[excel-vba]`tag there should be plenty of answers how to acomplish that.

Comment: Instead of creating new question, please edit your previous one to make it clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy cell.value based on if statement from an other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501908/copy-cell-value-based-on-if-statement-from-an-other-column)

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski you are right. I deleted the previous one. Sorry for that.